# MemCache: no room to 'put' - what happens?

Tags: memcached

I haven't coded/tested this yet, but assume that you have 2 *memcached instances* of very small size, e.g. 1Mb each.

What happens when each cache is full and you try to "put" another object into cache? Assume all objects in cache have infinite expiry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

When the table is full, subsequent inserts cause older data to be purged in least recently used (LRU) order